# sqlite3_step() does not return SQLITE_OK

Tags: sqlite

I have a data base, this is in my proyect how a file localDB.db I want update some information of a table in this since my aplication`s code the method I use is the follow:

```
-(void)establecePerfil:(int)idPerfil{

    while ([Utilidades consultaCargandoDatosDB]) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
    }
    [Utilidades cargandoDatos:YES];

    //perfil = [Perfil getInstance];
    [self cargarBaseDeDatos];

    NSLog(@"entre en establecer perfik");
    sqlite3 *dataBase;
    sqlite3_stmt *sentencia;
    if(sqlite3_open([self.dataBasePath UTF8String], &dataBase)==SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"entre en establecer perfik 2");

        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE perfiles SET \"seleccionado\"= 1, \"completado\"=0 WHERE \"id\"= %d", idPerfil];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataBase, [sql UTF8String], -1, &sentencia, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
            sqlite3_reset(sentencia);
            if(sqlite3_step(sentencia)==SQLITE_OK){
                NSLog(@"set profile OK");

            }
            else{
              //  NSAssert1(0, @"Error while selecting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(dataBase));
            NSLog( @"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(dataBase) );
                NSLog(@"%i", sqlite3_extended_errcode(dataBase));
                NSLog(@"%i",sqlite3_errcode(dataBase));
            }


        }
       sqlite3_finalize(sentencia);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"No se ha abierto la base de datos");
    }

    sqlite3_close(dataBase);


    [Utilidades cargandoDatos:NO];
}
```

I think, I have the problem in sqlite3_step(sentencia) because code error that appear after of else condition is 101 referencing to SQLITE_DONE so I don`t know that means this.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) says that SQLITE_DONE is correct (and SQLITE_OK would not be).

Comment: Really I replaced SQLITE_OK with SQLITE_DONE,error has been solved but  doesn`t update my database

Comment: This is not a forum. Your question is about the result code, and has been answered. If you have have a different question, ask it spearately.